# Date TIme Filter on Kendo UI for Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have been facing trouble implementing datetime filter using **Kendo UI for Angular 2**. Has anyone been able to work around this issue? If so please do let me know, hopefully with snippet on how to implement the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    <kendo-grid-column field="startTime" title="Started"
        [filter]="'date'" 
        format="{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}">
    </kendo-grid-column>
```